# Why am I getting a XML response instead of JSON?

Tags: java, php, json, spring

I need to generate a report so I communicate using Java Spring's RestTemplate to a php service. My code while communication to the php service is :-

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> response = null;

Gson gson = new Gson();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));
String reqBodyJSON = gson.toJson(reportPayload);
String Url = HmCommonProperty.getProperty("report_generate_url");
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(reqBodyJSON, headers);

try {
    response = template.postForEntity(Url, entity, String.class);
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    log.error("Exception occured with cause "+ex.getMessage());
}
```

On successful generation, it's supposed to return a json like this :-

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "status_message": "SUCCESS",
    "data": "FILE_CREATED"
}
```

If I hit the php service directly from Postman, I get the same success response. But from my RestTemplate, the response I get is not json at all. It's a weird xml like this: -

```xml
<200,<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: diagnostic_report in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\worksheet\mind_stretches_report\benchmark_reports.php</b> on line <b>198</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\worksheet\mind_stretches_report\benchmark_reports.php</b> on line <b>198</b><br />
{"status":200,"status_message":"SUCCESS","data":"FILE_CREATED"}<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  filesize(): stat failed for ./logger.log in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\worksheet\mind_stretches_report\log4php\appenders\LoggerAppenderRollingFile.php</b> on line <b>223</b><br />
,{Date=[Mon, 20 May 2019 09:07:07 GMT], Server=[Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.4], X-Powered-By=[PHP/7.0.4], Content-Length=[591], Keep-Alive=[timeout=5, max=100], Connection=[Keep-Alive], Content-Type=[application/json]}>
```

How do I get back the json I want instead of this xml response?

Comment: Thats a php error, It says you have an invalid `foreach`applied in `benchmark_reports.php` on `line 198`. If you solve this error, maybe it's fixed

Comment: Okay. But then why do I get the correct json if I hit the php service directly through postman?

Comment: I think that you are forgetting to send something with the RestTemplate, this is the only thing i can say with the information you gave me. I suggest you check what you are sending through

Comment: You're actually getting a correct response in your PHP code too. You can see it in the error message. But you are then trying to loop through a `json` with a `foreach` loop. That's not possible. It's a string. You probably want to use something like `json_decode` first.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the request you are sending via Postman, to the request sent by your PHP.

Are you sending the same request type?  The same variables?

The PHP script is expecting "diagnostic_report" to be set and it isn't.

Comment: It isn't an answer, i think it bettere to post it as a comment

Comment: I tried but didn't have 50 reputation...  I've got one less now thanks... ;)